# Sending Email receipt from Authorize.net transaction on my website

Tags: swiftmailer, authorize.net

I am using Authorize.net AIM on my website to accept donations/payments. Authorize.net automatically sends an email receipt to the customer once they have made the purchase, but I wish to disable this and send an email using my own email receipt template (in .html).
Previously I have sent emails using this format after I have inserted a username and email address into mySQL from a form on my website - it worked great. 
I now wish to do this same thing, but instead of inserting information into a database, using the information from their donation (amount, email address, confirmation) to send them an email.

I was using Swift to send the emails. This worked great.

How would I use php to do the same thing but with the information from my authorize.net coding?

Comment: If you're making the purchase using AIM then you have all of the informaton you need already so i don't understand what the question is here.

Comment: How do I use my working authorize.net to send a confirmation email using Swift...

Answer (score 0):

You could use Authorize.net's API and SDK and call the [GetTransactionDetailsRequest](https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sample-code-php/blob/master/TransactionReporting/get-transaction-details.php) with the transId and pipe the results to your customer's email with your own custom HTML email template.